Excluded-included point topology
I was introduced to included and excluded point topology fairly recently by my classmates and to my amazement the topologies mentioned worked for me in giving counter examples to many statements. I started thinking more and thought of generalising this concept by doing both that is excluding one point as well as including one point in all the open sets.
That is to say let $x_0, x_1\in X$ be two distinct points in $X$ then a subset $A$ is open in $X$ if it is $\emptyset, X$ or "it contains $x_0$ and does not contain $x_1$". 
One can check it actually forms a topology.
This topological space is of particular interest to me for two reasons, firstly the topology generated by taking the complements(that is the closed sets) can be shown to be same as that of this topology. Secondly any sequence converges to $x_1$ and any non constant sequence can never converge to $x_0$.
I went on further to define the collection $A_X(x_0,\cdots, x_r; y_0,\cdots,y_k)$ of subsets of $X$ as those subsets which contain the points $x_0,x_1,\cdots x_r$ and does not contain the points $y_0,y_1,\cdots,y_k$.
Any element of $A_X(x_0,\cdots, x_r; y_0,\cdots,y_k)$ will be called as an open set along with $\emptyset$ and the space $X$ itself. But too much abstraction kills the essence, in my opinion.
However I'd like to read more about these things, if such already exist in the literature.
Thank you.

That is an interesting definition, though I’ve never seen it in the literature before. (Then again, I’m not a topologist, so perhaps other people have defined this and I’ve just never seen it.) I assume it’s just, for the sake of producing examples and counterexamples, included point and excluded point topologies already suffice, so there’s not much point in extending the definitions. And as far as I can tell (correct me if I’m wrong), the excluded point topology doesn’t have much application apart from serving as a counterexample…

(The included point topology is a model for generic points, so perhaps people in algebraic geometry and related fields might consider it interesting?)

You can use either \emptyset $\emptyset$ or \varnothing $\varnothing$ as symbols for the empty set. using $\phi$ left me wondering for some time whether $\phi$ was supposed to be a function, or the symbol for some condition.

Your comment that the co-topology is the same is wrongly stated. It is also a topology of this same class, but is obviously not the same topology, since all the open sets of the first contain $x_0$ and none of the open sets in the second do. Similarly in your discussion of sequences, while it is easy to figure out what you really meant, every statement you made is not correct: if $X =\Bbb R, x_0 = 0, x_1 = 1$, then $0, 1,1,1,\dots$ is a non-constant sequence converging to $1$, and not to $0$. Please be more careful in your descriptions.

@PaulSinclair when I said that they're the same, I meant it structure wise that is I can define a map from one to another preserving the structure. In this case homeomorphism.

@PaulSinclair Also the comment stays the same. The sequence 0,1,1,1... is a non constant sequence hence it can not converge to $x_0=0$

You can only define such a map if $r = k$. Even with the extension in my answer, such a map is possible only if $A$ and $B$ are equinumerable. As for my other remark, I accidently switched the roles of $x_0, x_1$ in my example. $1,0,0,0,\dots$ is a non-constant sequence converging to $0$ (but also to $1$, as you are correct that every sequence converges to $1$). Limits depend only on the tail of a sequence. Changes involving only a finite number of elements have no impact on the limit. Again, it was clear what you meant in both cases, but the way you actually worded it was not correct.

@PaulSinclair apologies. I stated it a bit loosely. As a side note is this topology or the more general case you gave in any way useful?

All topologies are good for examples, such as showing that yes, a topology can include both discrete and indiscrete points. For specific applications, I am not aware of any. However, it is an incredibly big world out there, and I am only familiar with a tiny bit of it.

In your generalization, there is no reason I can see to restrict yourself to finite sets. I would define more generally for some some disjoint sets $A, B \subset X$, the topology $$T(A,B) = \{\emptyset, X\} \cup \{U \subseteq X : A\subseteq U, U \cap B = \emptyset\}.$$
Far from "killing the essence", I find this to clarify it. First note that the cases of $A = B = \emptyset$ gives the discrete topology, while $A = X, B = \emptyset$ and $A = \emptyset,B = X$ both give the trivial topology.
But more generally, the comparison of $T(A,B)$ to your original included point-excluded point topology (call it $\tau$) makes something clear: This generalization - which includes your own - barely adds anything. $T(A,B)$ makes no distinction what-so-ever between different points of $A$, nor does it make any between different points of $B$. The only difference between $\tau(x_0, x_1)$ and $T(A, B)$ is that we've replaced the single point $x_0$ with a blob $A$ that is treated like a single point, and the single point $x_1$ is replaced with the blob $B$ which is also treated like a single point. The only new thing that $T(A, B)$ accomplishes is to throw away the $T_0$ status of $\tau$.
